# how to generate manually a route to easyadmin

Tags: symfony, routes, easyadmin

I'm using `easyadmin` for my website. In order to manage a gallery of images I would like to display a thumbnail of each one of them wrapped in a link that lead to the actual `show` action of the entity `Image`

here is the definition of the gallery :

```
Album:
    class: App\Entity\Album
        list:
            fields:
                - titre
                - images
            show:
                fields:
                    - titre
                    - { property: images, template: admin/field_mosaic.html.twig }
```

And the custom template I have created :

```
<div class="gallery m-2">
    {% for image in item.images %}
        <a href="{{ path('easy_admin_bundle') }}?entity={{ link_parameters.entity }}&action={{ link_parameters.action }}&primary_key_name={{ link_parameters.primary_key_name }}&id={{ item.id }}">
            <img class="rounded m-2" src="{{ asset(vich_uploader_asset(image, "imageFile"))|imagine_filter('profile_list') }}" alt="image #{{ loop.index }}">
        </a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Unfortunately I don't know the name of the main route of the easyadminbundle. I tried `{{ path('admin') }}`which doesn't worked and the name in the `routes\easy_admin.yaml` file which doesn't work either.

Where can I found it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 10 min I decided to run a simple

```
$php bin/console debug:router
```

And I found this little one:

```
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                                                    |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | easyadmin                                                                                |
| Path         | /admindatabase/                                                                          |
| Path Regex   | #^/admindatabase/$#sD                                                                    |
| Host         | ANY                                                                                      |
| Host Regex   |                                                                                          |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                                                      |
| Method       | ANY                                                                                      |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                                                                |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                                                          |
| Defaults     | _controller: EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\EasyAdminController::indexAction |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler                                  |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Sorry for bothering....